# Change static tableview cell height dynamically

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a tableview. I created it from storyboard it is a static tableview.(I am using it for profile settings).

But i have to change height of the first row of this table view dynamically and **i don't want to change other cell heights.** **They should use their storyboard height values.** How can i do this?

I tried following code:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        return 100
    }
    return (tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.bounds.height)!
}
```

**But this is setting 100 for all cells.**

My tableview:

[image]

Comment: Use [`UItableView.automaticDimension`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewautomaticdimension). Make sure constraints are proper.

Answer (score -1):

Use the following override function..

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
if indexPath.row == 0 {
    return 100
}
    return UITableView.automaticDimension
}
```

But you have to make sure that every item in the static tableview have (top/bottom/left/right) constraints. it only works when it have all these constraints on it.

Comment: What happens if i use auto dimension also for row zero and change for row zero’s height constraint?

Comment: no need to call `heightForRowAt ` method if you have setup constraint of views/cells properly. or just put here `return UITableView.automaticDimension`